# How to create my own modifier key using HID on OSX Sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-sierra, hid, nsevent

Recently Karabiner (the great OSX remapping tool) stopped working on Sierra.

I just [read](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) that it is possible to remap keys with HID and I tried the example code below, which remaps `a` and `b`. However it's not clear how to create my own modifier key (say Modifier-X), for example TAB to Modifier-X.

Then create mappings such as TAB+X -> Launch Program X , etc...

Karabiner supported this, now Karabiner does not work, so I am trying to find another way to make this happen.

Any suggestions how can this be implemented with HID ?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDEventSystemClient.h>

#import <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDServiceClient.h>

#import <IOKit/hid/IOHIDUsageTables.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IOHIDEventSystemClientRef system;
    CFArrayRef services;

    uint64_t aKey = 0x700000004;
    uint64_t bKey = 0x700000005;

    NSArray *map = @[
                     @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(aKey),
                        @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(aKey)},
                     @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(bKey),
                        @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(bKey)},
                     ];

    system = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreateSimpleClient(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    services = IOHIDEventSystemClientCopyServices(system);
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(services); i++) {
        IOHIDServiceClientRef service = (IOHIDServiceClientRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(services, i);
        if(IOHIDServiceClientConformsTo(service, kHIDPage_GenericDesktop, kHIDUsage_GD_Keyboard)) {
            IOHIDServiceClientSetProperty(service, CFSTR(kIOHIDUserKeyUsageMapKey), (CFArrayRef)map);
        }
    }

    CFRelease(services);
    CFRelease(system);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's possible to do this at the `NSEvent` level. I've modified the tags, so as to allow one of the resident experts to find the question.